# Top modal form close in nested modal forms closes all other modal forms?

Tags: delphi, forms, modal-dialog

When form A is modal and it displays a second modal form B, and the modal result for B is set and B then closes, A is also closed.

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true, there has to be some other problem in your code. Setting `ModalResult` will affect only the currently modal form. Try this very simple example:

- Create a new form
- Drop a button onto it
- In the button `OnClick` event handler add this code:

  ```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    with TForm1.Create(Self) do begin
      if ShowModal = mrCancel then
        Self.Color := RGB(Random(256), Random(256), Random(256));
    end;
  end;
  ```

You will observe that each button press creates a new modal form, and you can repeat this as often as you wish. Closing a form will set its `ModalResult` to `mrCancel` and re-enable the parent form. To exit the application you will need to close all forms, one by one, in the opposite order of creation.

Comment: Correct, after some searching and testing I found that - wait for it - "somehow......" the button had a ModalResult of mrNo and after the second dialog closed, the right thing was done by the form class and the dialog was closed.